# After which verbs there shouldn’t be partitive article?

Tags: articles

I’ve noticed that before "vin", when one wants to say that he likes it, there is no partitive article: *j’aime le vin*. But the rule says, that a partitive article **must** be used before uncountable/abstract things: *-Nous achetons de fromage.- Quel fromage est-ce que vous achetez? - On achete du fromage belle*

So, *aimer* is an exception? Is there any verbs that break the rule?

Comment: Browse the [article](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles) and the [partitive](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partitif) tags.

Answer (score 5):

*J'aime le vin/j'aime les pommes. Nous achetons des pommes/de bonnes pommes/ du bon fromage/nous achetons le vin (le fromage, les fruits) au supermarché.*

Whether you use the definite article (*le la les*) on its own or with de before it depends on the meaning you give to the noun. The fact that *aimer* is very often followed by the definite article without *de* is a question of semantics. It's because *aimer* expresses a general idea. It's the same with *détester, préférer, adorer,...* but you will find (probably rare) cases where those verbs are followed by the partitive article.

See https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles and https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partitif

<sub>Note: Laure's comments converted to an answer.</sub>

If we consider the following sentence:

***J'aime les hommes mais j'ai détesté des hommes qui méprisaient les femmes.***

*J'aime **les** hommes*: *hommes* here is used in a generic sense, no specific group of men is determined → no partitive article.

*des hommes qui méprisaient **les** femmes*: *femmes* here is used in a generic sense, no specific group of women is determined → no partitive article.

*J'ai détesté **des** hommes qui méprisaient les femmes*: we use the partitive article because the relative clause *qui méprisaient des femmes* define the group "men", we are no longer talking about men in general but about a specific group of men. Note also that the verb is in a past tense (*ai détesté* : passé composé), if the verb was in the present tense we would no longer be talking about a specific group of men but about men in general. So we need two things to determine the specificity of the group : the tense (past) and the determiner (relative clause).

Answer (score 0):

The use of the partitive article is  ruled by the verb as far as the concept of the verb can apply naturally to a partial quantity of the matter.

Verbs as the following are of this type.

- prendre, manger, boire, mâcher,  se servir, faire cuire, préparer,…

*Il boit **de** l'eau.• Les enfants mangent **de** la compote de pomme.• Elle fait cuire **du** riz. • Ils leur ont servi **du** vin. …*

Other verbs cannot imply a small quantity taken as part of a whole but instead they apply to a type of thing or a specific thing and partitives are not used with those in as  natural a  way as those of the preceding sort; they are verbs as the following.

- aimer, haïr, apprécier, priser, avoir une préférence, connaitre,…

*Ils aiment **le** vin.• Ils n'apprécient pas **les** pommes de terre.• Elle a une préférence pour **le** théatre.• Il ne connait pas **le** vin. …• Elle a aimé **ce** vin.• Ils apprécient **ce** plat de pommes de terre.*

*Exception for the word "monde"*

- Son frère connait du monde qui s'intéresse à ça.
- (*contrast*) Elle connait **un** riz dont les grains sont plus longs.
- (*apparently this is not said.*) <s>Elle connait du riz dont les grains sont plus longs.</s>

If you want to express a partial quantity of things that are truly countable, as for instance some of the sorts of wines, or olives you use a numerical determiner.

- Ils mangent quelques unes des olives que l'on trouve ici, mais beaucoup d'autres ils ne les aiment pas.
- Ces touristes boivent peu des vins de la région.
- (contrast) Ces touristes boivent peu du vin de la région, ils consomment plutôt du vin de grand cru.

So let's take a look at your sentences.

- J’aime le vin. *correct, there is no partitive.*

You must understand the rule differently: a partitive article is used only if you need to specify a small quantity out of a whole and the things can be concrete (pain, eau, cement, air, …) and abstract (liberté, bonheur, …).

- <s>Nous achetons de fromage.</s> *Almost correct; "fromage" is masculine, therefore you would have to say "de le", but as this is always contracted into "du", you say "Nous achetons **du** fromage.".
- Quel fromage est-ce que vous achetez? - <s>On achete du fromage belle</s> *Not correct; the adjective is not idiomatic; here you must say "bon" and you must place the adjective before the noun; Quel fromage est-ce que vous achetez? - On achête du bon fromage.*